# Bluetooth SPP and other Bluetooth Services

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am new to Android development, and am clueless to how Bluetooth really works other than connecting two devices wirelessly. I have been using the BluetoothChat example, as well as an example in an Android book I have bought. They both look EXTREMELY similar, but I am confused.

For clarification, the Android application I am working on connects my Android device to an embedded Bluetooth chip. From what I have figured out, the Bluetooth chip is the server of the pair.

Anyway, in the example it states

```
Currently this only does Bluetooth SPP. This can be generalized to other services.
```

I have looked into what SPP means, but still don't fully understand it, and haven't figured out alternative 'services' that the example is talking about.

Can anyone simplify SPP, explain what alternative services could be used, and why they would be used? And if possible, try to explain which service would work best for my situation, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPP stands for `Serial Port Profile`.  It essentially is just a wireless serial port connection, like a RS 232 connection.  This type of connection is used for basic data streaming.  There are many Bluetooth profiles for different things.  Take a look at the list here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile

In my app, as well as the BluetoothChat app, the `Serial Port Profile` is used for establishing a `Socket` connection.  Each profile is optimized for the task they are designed for.